# If $fg$ is smooth, are $f$ and $g$ necessarily smooth?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f,g : U \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. If the product $fg$ is smooth, i.e. of class $C^{\infty}$, is it then true, that also $f$ and $g$ must be of class $C^\infty$?

I would tend that to this is false, but I cannot come up with a proof nor a counterexample.

Comment: $f = 1/x$ and $g = x$, $f$ is not smooth at $x = 0$.

Comment: @Gregory Yes, but the functions should be defined on an open set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy example: Take $U$ to be any open interval of positive length, $f = 0$, and $g$ any nonsmooth function (of which there are many choices).

Answer (score 6):

Let $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\Bbb Q$ and $f(x)=2$ otherwise, and let $g(x):=1/f(x)$.

Comment: Exactly the example I had in mind. Both $f$ and $g$ are very unsmooth.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the most general example.  Let $h$ be any smooth function.  Let $f$ be *any* function whatsoever such that $f(x)$ is nonzero for all $x$ such that $h(x)$ is nonzero.  Define $g(x)=h(x)/f(x)$ when $f(x)\neq 0$, and define $g(x)$ in any way you want when $f(x)=0$.  Then $fg=h$ is smooth, but $f$ and $g$ certainly don't have to be smooth since $f$ can be chosen almost completely arbitrarily.